# Test key generation with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am generating a key in Rails app.

The key is generated in `Key` class in `self.generate` (no arguments) method. I can easily implement the method, but how do I test in `rspec` that my method attempts to regenerate a key if the key already exists in my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to `stub` a method that returns you a key and `unstub` after the first call:

```
it 'generates a second key if the first one is not unique' do
    Key.create uid: "be81ed3a9c3a"
    SecureRandom.stub(:hex).with(6) {
        SecureRandom.unstub(:hex)
        "be81ed3a9c3a"
    }
    expect(Key.generate.uid).not_to eq("be81ed3a9c3a")
end
```